Star Tracker Absolute Accuracy
Blue Canyon Technologies states their standard nano star tracker accuracy is about the cross-axis (6 arcsec) and boresight (40 arcsec). How do I calculate the absolute accuracy the star tracker would provide?

What do you mean by absolute accuracy?

who or what is BTC?  I think it's best if you include a quote of the particular section of information from "BTC" that you are referring to for context. Thanks!

@uhoh Apparently the questioner is asking about Blue Canyon Technologies' Gen2 standard nano star tracker. The specs match the values in the question. What the questioner means by "absolute accuracy", who knows?

By Absolute accuracy, I meant the resultant star tracker accuracy.

Can you elaborate on where the absolute or resultant metric will be used? The separate numbers for cross axis and boresight axis gives more information than a single resultant number would. Are you trying to compare it to other sensors where only a resultant accuracy specification is available?

btw, from FAQ see How do comment @replies work? Unless a user has clicked "follow" on your post, they may not automatically get a notification that you have replied in a comment unless you use the @.

Thanks @uhoh , I am still new to this.

@AJN I want to compute the Pointing Knowledge and Pointing Accuracy of the system. So for Pointing Knowledge calculations, I am trying to find the resultant Star Tracker Accuracy.

@v_space That depends on what your metric is, which may depend on your architecture and mission objectives. For a narrow field of view parallel to the tracker axis, the cross-axis uncertainty is what you want. For a field of view perpendicular to the tracker axis, the boresight uncertainty dominates.

@JohnDoty I'll be locking to three stars to get the quaternions. So should I be only worried about the X and the Y axis accuracies?

@v_space Depends on what you're using the quaternion for. The covariances of the quaternion elements will reflect the different accuracies about the axes.

For small angles, rotations commute [1], [2].
For small angles, the two angle values can be seen as components of a vector and the magnitude of the vector would be $\sqrt{6^2 + 40^2}$. This angle might be a candidate for absolute accuracy.
Another method :
One can construct two rotation matrices to represent the rotations about bore sight axis and cross axis, combine them, and compute the angle for the combined rotation from the resulting matrix (Similar to what is done in [2]).
Note : Since we don't know how the accuracy number is arrived at for a given particular model, the above calculations might be only one of the many possible sources for error in the final system.

The above is only a guess from my part and i suggest improving the question and waiting for other answers.

I have been doing a sqrt(6^2+6^2+40^2) because the cross would be both x-axis and y-axis. But I was wondering if the absolute accuracy dropped this significantly due to the bore error in a practical use case.

I don't know if the cross axis number is a resultant of both the cross axes. If so, then only $\sqrt{6^2+40^2}$ is required. Can't comment if boresight axis accuracy will really play any role in a practical case. I would assume that it does affect the accuracy.

the cross axis accuracy is not the resultant of both cross axis in this case
